# Why is $\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}=\overline{\exp(\mathbb{C})}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> > Why is $\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}=\overline{\exp(\mathbb{C})}$?

I do not know how one can see that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: $\exp(\Bbb C)=\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Consider $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$, then $z=\exp(q)$ for $\mathbb{C}\ni q=\log(z)$, so $z\in\exp(\mathbb{C})$. Now consider $s\in\exp(\mathbb{C})$, then $s=\exp(v)$ for a $v\in\mathbb{C}$, i.e. $s=\sum\limits_{n=0}\frac{v^n}{n!}=1+v+\frac{v^2}{2}+...\neq 0$, so $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$. Is this right?

Comment: It's very close (and certainly the right approach). For the first bit, you'll want to note that we can choose a branch cut of the logarithm that misses $z,$ and choosing any branch of the logarithm , we can set $q=\log(z)$ and proceed as you did. For the second bit, since the power series' radius of convergence is infinite, then we know $s\in\Bbb C,$ since $v\in\Bbb C$. You'll still need to justify that $s\ne 0,$ but once you have, you're done.